# Saber o tempo de leitura de URL

Tags: java

Estou lendo o conteúdo que tem uma url

Usando o seguinte bloco de código:

```
String urlNormal = "http://minhaurl";
URLConnection conn = urlNormal.openConnection();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu saber quanto tempo custo para ele ler os dados ou quanto tempo passou tentando ler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia ser assim:

```
long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();

String urlNormal = "http://minhaurl";
URLConnection conn = urlNormal.openConnection();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

long fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Tempo: " + (fim - inicio));
```

Te dá o tempo em ms.

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
    //Registrar tempo inicial:
    long time_begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Declarar URL, e criar objeto do tipo URL:
    String example_your_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
    URL url = new URL(example_your_URL);

    //Abrir conexão:
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    //Registrar tempo final:
    long time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Tempo gasto:
    double milliseconds = (time_end - time_begin);

    //Imprimir tempo gasto:
    System.out.println("Tempo em milissegundos: " + milliseconds+"\n");

    //Ler conteúdo:
    String content = null;
    while( (content = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(content);
    }
```